# Manipulating Blueprism collection

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I have two collections, One collection contains information as follows.

Collection 1 includes following details, It has only one row.
|NAME|AGE|CITY|
|:----|:---:|:----|
|AA  | 20|NEW |

Collection 2 includes following details, it has multiple rows but only two columns.
|NAME OF COLUMN|NEW COLUMN|
|:--------------|:----------|
|NAME          |FIRST NAME|
|AGE           |YEARS|
|CITY          |PLACE|

I am running a loop with the collection 2. I need the Blueprism to select the value in first cell of the collection 1.

Normally if I want to select value in the first cell of the collection 1 I type following expression in Blueprim.

```
[Collection 1.NAME]
```

But this time I want the Collection 1 field 1 as the first value of the collection 2.

I tried following.

1. `[Collection 1.[Collection 2.NAME OF COLUMN]]`
   The above produces a Syntax error. The token "]" is invalid.
2. I set the value from Collection 2 to a new variable (data item) SAY "columnName"

   [Collection 1.[columnName]]
   The above produces a Syntax error. The token "]" is invalid.

Since I am running this in a loop, every time the loop runs the field name automatically changes.

How to do this....?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Get Field Value` action from the `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO within your loop to achieve this:

**Inputs**

- Collection - `[Collection 1]`
- Field Name - `[Collection 2.Name of Column]`
- Row Index - `0`

[image]

Set your **Outputs** however your logic would dictate (it's not clear from your post what *exactly* you're trying to do here).